# Upgraded Excel and now visual studio won't let me run my add-in project

Tags: javascript, excel, visual-studio-2013

I get the error:
"The application associated with this project type isn't installed on this computer", when I try and run my visual studio Pro 2013 javascript API add-in that I have written for Excel.
I had to upgrade my Excel from 2013 to 2016, so I am guessing this is the problem. i.e. the project is associated with Excel 2013 but that is no longer on my computer at all. 
So the question is, how do I associate my project with Excel 2016 instead of 2013.  There doesn't seem to be any obvious way (as per normal with Microsoft, nothing is ever simple.)
Thanks in advance.
Stuart

Comment: Are you using the Interop DLL or something else to access Excel?

Comment: Not using anything specific as far as I know.  I just pick an excel template.  I don't remember adding anything to do with Excel at all.  I think there must be a reference somewhere in my project, but no idea where.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade to the latest version of Microsoft Office Interop Libraries here, [https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Am using VS 2013.  Is there something for 2013?  The link is to 2015.  Am reluctant to upgrade my VS.

Comment: This has a link to an August 2015 update to Office Dev tools for Visual Studio 2013. If that does not work then it is likely that you cannot develop Office 2016 integrations using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Have upgraded but it still does not work.  However the message is not implying that it will not work, simply that the project type isn't installed on my computer, so I don't think upgrading to VS2016 is going to make any difference.  Don't forget I have upgraded Office, not the other way around.  I'm reluctant to upgrade VS and risk upsetting all my projects, whilst also paying more money if it isn't going to work.

Comment: So, does anyone know where you associate an application (Excel) with a VS project?

Comment: Note, my project works fine if I open it from with-in Excel 2016, as an add-in, but that is no good for debugging in VS.

Comment: Can anyone answer this?  Still unanswered.  The upgrade suggested does not work.